# Replicate a Hosting Database to a Local Database in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, hosting

I'm new in Laravel and I need to replicate or sync the Database on my hosting to a Local Database on my PC. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really anything to do with PHP or Laravel. You should use the tools provided for your database management system to copy the data.

Comment: I've found TablePlus to be extremely helpful in providing a nice GUI to run db dumps and imports.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way will be for you to export your database from your database on the server and import it locally and make sure your model match the database imported.

Also, you can try database replication. Check out [Replication - MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html)

Comment: You can use mysqldump command for export. Example command `mysqldump -u DB_username -p DB_Name > backup.sql` Example command for import `mysql -u DB_username -p DB_name < backup.sql` You can find export and import examples on the following link. https://www.webdeyaz.com/mysql-yedek-alma-ve-yedegi-geri-yuekleme/702328